# Display the whole world with maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, zooming

i am developing an app, and i want to show the whole world. I am using google maps api v2, and i can't set zoom level less than 2. 
Is there any way to display the whole world with google api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do that. This is stated in the documentation that the lowest zoom level can be 2, but also depends on the map size in pixels. On bigger screens you can have it limited from 3 or possibly higher.

You are welcome to post a feature request on gmaps-api-issues site.

I suspect this limitation is there to force not to show more than half of the world and current implementation cannot handle it correctly. See this issue: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5285

Comment: Actually it is said that 1 is the minimal: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom . Anyway, requested about it now: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11510

Comment: @androiddeveloper The question and answer are from 2013. A lot has changed since then... Good to know they fixed my issue #5285 and that they changed min zoom from 2 to 1.

Comment: So it is possible now to show entire world? I tried a lot and failed : http://stackoverflow.com/q/42329186/878126

Comment: Its possible via `MapView` (or `MapFragment`) [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite). For details please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719385/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The lowest zoom level supported changes on each device based on the screen size and density, and also depends on the map size.

You can use [GoogleMap.getMinimumZoomLevel()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMinZoomLevel()) to find out what it is for your map.

You may be able to see the whole world with the Lite Mode.