# How to show entire world and put markers on it?

Tags: android, gis

### Background

I want to show the popular map of the entire world, and put markers on it.

### The problem

I tried to use Google Maps for it, but it seems ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17561414/878126)) it doesn't support zooming out enough to show the entire world.

### What I've found

Looking on Wikipedia ([**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_centre_of_Earth)), the center of the earth is on  **30°00′N 31°00′E** , but this seems to be in Egypt, and it doesn't look like the center of the world map, even on the Wikipedia page itself:

[image]

I've also found a similar question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838367/878126), so I've converted it to Android code:

```
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            LatLngBounds allowedBounds = new LatLngBounds(
                    new LatLng(-85, 180),    // bottom right corner
                    new LatLng(85, -180)    // top left corner of map
            );
            double k = 5.0f;
            double n = allowedBounds.northeast.latitude - k;
            double e = allowedBounds.northeast.longitude - k;
            double s = allowedBounds.southwest.latitude + k;
            double w = allowedBounds.southwest.longitude + k;
            LatLng neNew = new LatLng(n, e);
            LatLng swNew = new LatLng(s, w);
            LatLngBounds boundsNew = new LatLngBounds(swNew, neNew);
            googleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(boundsNew);
        }
    });
```

But it does't show entire world at all:

[image]

I've also tried to play with the zoom (looking [**here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#zoom)), but it never zoomed out enough to show as much as continents:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(30, 31), 1));
```

[image]

I chose "1", because the docs say that "1" is the value for "world":

> The following list shows the approximate level of detail you can
>   expect to see at each zoom level:
>
> 1: World

### The question

How can I show the entire world on Google Maps ?

Or, is there any good alternative to just show the world map (static image is good too), and be able to put markers on it? Maybe even using a VectorDrawable?

Is there an image I can show, and somehow put markers on it?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: @yosriz No, but what we did for now, that works in our case alone (it's just a POC anyway), is to put the map as image in ImageVIew, within a FrameLayout, set the scaleType to be from start (top left corner will be the same for both the content and the view), set I'mageView's height to be match_parent and width as wrap_content, and put the on-top views in relation to the ImageView's size, because the content of the ImageView should fit the same size that it got to be. Again, this is a very specific case, so it's not a nice solution at all.

Comment: So you basically create custom view with overlay view for each country? Did you consider using Google GeoChart?

Comment: Hello anyone found this proper  solution? i used liteMode in mapview but its not showing world map.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to show entire World and put markers on it with `MapView` (or `MapFragment`) [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite):

> ... If you need to show the
>   entire world in the viewport, it may be better to use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite).

Markers is in "Partly" [Supported Features](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite#supported_api_features):

> You can add a marker and respond to a
>   click event. You can also add custom marker icons. It's not possible
>   to make a marker draggable. Markers on a lite mode map are flat, and
>   they cannot be rotated.

Also, you can use other features like lines and polygon drawing, etc.

So, with `MainActivity` like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";

    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(31.755983, 35.212879))
                        .title("Jerusalem"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }
    }
}
```

and `activity_main.xml` (also its possible to set Lite Mode for `MapView` programmatically via [`GoogleMapOptions.liteMode(true)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions.html#liteMode(boolean))):

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="1"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:liteMode="true"
    />
```

you got something like that:

[image: Google Maps Whole World]

Comment: This looks promising! Sadly I've moved forward from this question a long time ago. Can you please put a Github sample for this, so that I could quickly check it out (sadly I don't have much time recent) ? For now, I will give you +1 for the effort. If the sample works, I will accept the answer.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Thanks! I can do it in a couple of days, but actually, all source code is in answer text. You can just create empty activity project, configure int for google maps and replace text of `MainActivity.java` and `activity_main.xml` by text from the answer. It really works.

Comment: Please do. I will appreciate it.

Comment: I used liteMode in MapView but didn't get this type of output. I also need to show world map .

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to see the whole world using [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite) in the Google Maps Android API.

You can add markers on it the same as you would with the full map mode.

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible solution using Google Static Maps API.

The query is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=510x480&center=0,0&zoom=1&scale=2&key=YOUR_KEY
```

Just play around with the size parameters to test the desired view.

[image: Static Map API]

Comment: Is this the API used on Android? Or do you show the one of the web? I know that for the web it's available, but not for Android (native functions). To me it seems what you show is for the web alone.

Comment: You said: _" is there any good alternative to just show the world map (static image is good too"_. I assumed you needed a static map to render in your app so you do not need this. 
Currently, there is no way you can zoom out a map and achieve a level 1 view because, even if you set your orientation to landscape to facilitate this, mobile view-ports are limited to a max level 3 or 4 zoom.

Comment: You missed an important thing, which is the first sentence: "I want to show the popular map of the entire world, and put markers on it." .