# TileOverlay#getTile starts at zoom level 3

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to build a Map with custom tiles using the Google Maps Android SDK. I've checked out the [TileOverlayDemoActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/TileOverlayDemoActivity.java) of the [android-samples](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples) Github repository.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay#coordinates) at Zoom level 0 a single image will be requested, on zoom level 1 a total of 4 images and so on. Currently I'm facing the problem that **immediately** after loading the map the `TileProvider#getTitle` is getting **called with zoom level 3** and there is no way for me to zoom out. Even if I display the zoom controls the "-" is disabled.

#### What I have tried

I figured it might be related to the `Camera` so I tried calling the following

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(0.0f));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't have any effect. Same goes for the following

```
map.setMinZoomPreference(0);
```

Currently I don't know what the issue might be.

Following my code. It's basically the same as in the linked demo activity I've just changed the `UrlTileProvider` to my own.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    map.setMinZoomPreference(0);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(0.0f));

    TileProvider tileProvider = new TileProvider() {
        @Override
        public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {
            String name = "tile_" + Integer.toString(zoom) + "_" + Integer.toString(x) + "_" + Integer.toString(y);
            Resources resources = getResources();
            final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());

            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();

            return new Tile(256, 256, bitmapdata);
        }
    };

    mapTiles = map.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(tileProvider));
}
```

Maybe it's worth mentioning what `map.getCameraPosition()` returns:

```
CameraPosition{target=lat/lng: (0.0,0.0), zoom=2.0, tilt=0.0, bearing=0.0}
```

#### tl;dr

How can I set the Map to zoom level 0?

#### Edit

According to the comment and answer I tried to activate `Lite Mode` and set the zoom level via XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="1"
    map:mapType="normal"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Unfortunately without any effect. It still starts requesting at zoom level 3.

Comment: Did you try to set it in the xml of the SupportMapFragment?

Comment: Just did, unfortunately doesn't work either.

Comment: You miss `map:liteMode="true"` in fragment XML for Lite Mode.

Comment: Oops, my fault. With this property it seems to zoom out however zooming itself isn't working anymore. I guess that's what you mean in your comment regarding "lite mode isn't working with a TileProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that is impossible to set zoom level to 0 because minimal zoom level is 1 [from documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#zoom):

> The following list shows the approximate level of detail you can
>   expect to see at each zoom level:
>
> ```
> 1: World
> 5: Landmass/continent
> 10: City
> 15: Streets
> 20: Buildings
> ```

also from documentation:

> **Note:** Due to screen size and density, some devices may not support the
>   lowest zoom levels. Use [`GoogleMap.getMinimumZoomLevel()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMinZoomLevel()) to get the
>   minimum zoom level possible for the map. If you need to show the
>   entire world in the viewport, it may be better to use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite).

So, use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) to show the entire world in the viewport.

Comment: I have to admit all of this sounds promising unfortunately it doesn't work. `#getMinZoomLevel` returns 0.0f. Settings the zoom level to 1.0f has no effect - same goes for LiteMode.

Comment: @user3420815 It definitely works with Lite Mode (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719385/6950238)), but Tile Provide didn't works in Lite Mode.